# Best HTTP Response Code for a Restful API which makes calls to other Web Services when a failure occurs

Tags: rest, service, api-design

I'm designing a Restful API that makes calls to other web services aggregates the result and return back to the client. If connection of any of the other web services fails for any reason, what is the best thing to return?

Right now am returning an 500 - Internal Server error to the client but I would like to return more details to the client on what made the request to fail. Would it be redundant to return a 500 http response code with a response body containing a message detailing where the error actually occurred or to just return a 503 - Service Unavailable http response code?

Answer (score 4):

Your response code should depend on what you can do with the request. If clients can expect in this case to receive partial information and a message indicating what remote data feeds are unavailable, then send back a 200. I would not include HTTP codes or failing URIs in that response, just the names of the providers that are unavailable, and possibly a reason why. If you do, you may find yourself broken when you need to add non-URI-based providers.  If you must, then make sure to include a "type" and require clients to use it. This will partially future-proof you, but expect that many clients will ignore the type and break if you add new types later.

If clients can't do anything with partial data, then you should return a 503 because your service is unavailable. It happens to be unavailable because a remote server it relies on is down. That's no different than returning a 503 because your own database is down. Your API can't return something because something it needs isn't available right now, but will be again later. You should include in the body of the response the reason for the outage, and may include a `Retry-After` header if you have any idea as to when the remote server might be available again.

A 404 is not appropriate because it means that the resource being requested does not exist - an error by the client. The resource does exist, it just can't be returned right now, because your server can't build it.

A 409 is not appropriate because there is no conflict that the user can resolve.

A 206 is not appropriate because it is to be used when the request includes a `Range` header, and there's no indication these requests do.

Answer (score 1):

Since your aggregation is basically not finding what it seeks, perhaps **HTTP 404 Not Found** is appropriate.

If not all remote calls fail, so there at least are some relevant results, you could return HTTP 200 OK with an additional status informing that some remote sources currently are unavailable.

I would not return HTTP 503, as this code implies that **your** service is temporarily unavailable - and you therefore suggest the client retries later. HTTP 503 is typically returned when a server is restarting and is not quite ready to serve requests.

Comment: So basically I call one service to get a key and then I call another to retrieve some data. Are you saying in a scenario where the data retrieval fail cause the remote server is unavailable I should return a 404 to the client?

Comment: Yes - in that case, I would return 404 - because your data was not found. Perhaps, HTTP 409 (Conflict) sounds more relevant, but it is rarely used.

Comment: You could perhaps aggregate the responses: Source1 returns HTTP 200 and results, Source2 returns 404, Source3 returns HTTP 200 and so on

Comment: There is also HTTP 206 Partial Content - which could sound like your business case. However, it seems the intent is rather for large resumable downloads. Please note that the REST client receiving your 404 may present it however they want; e.g. as a nice 'No results found' or 'Remote servers down'.

Comment: Basically the client doesn't know the internal Implementation of the API. Wouldn't returning multiple HTTP status codes be confusing? Also would it not be misleading if I returned a 404 since technically the resource may be available but I could not retrieve it at that time.

Comment: Well - it depends on the business case. It seems you have a scenario where you have partial results - which is still a success - even though it is not a complete success. The question is how to relay this to the client. If the client just needs to know that some sources were unavailable, you could return HTTP 200 OK with a short message indicating that. If the client needs to know which sources were not available, I would aggregate the results as above